# RewriteRule - html broken - Like missing css

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$ more.php?books=$1&tags=$2 [L]
```

After this rule everything works but page is displayed incorrectly. Like missing css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you check the browser view source and click the css link? Also check the css path.

Comment: I created a link like this book-name/2 and then the path css to become wrong. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen, when you have a relative URL to your CSS files. If you access the URL `/book-name/2` and have a link to `css/style.css`, for example, the browser will resolve this to `/book-name/css/style.css`.

Change your CSS links to absolute URLs, like `/css/style.css`, and you should be fine.

Comment: Worth noting that a path starting with `/` will always start in the root folder.